# Converting a trained RGB resnet50 model to grayscale

Tags: deep-learning, grayscale, mxnet

Is there are direct way to convert a trained RGB resnet50 mxnet model to grayscale.
I'm just looking so save some CPU cycles not having to process 3 channels in the the first layer since my input images are grayscale anyway. I'd also like to avoid having to stack 3 grayscale images to create a 3 channel input.

Looking at the params, the first layer that seems to be 3 channels in pretty deep. Does this mean the channels are processed separately and only joined deeper in the model.

[image: resnet50 params]

I'm working with night vision images.

Comment: you cannot. Since the layers are built for 3 channels and the weights are built for 3 channels you cannot do transfer learning. 
But you can look for the model architecture code, edit it for grayscale i.e. single channel (its going to be a rollercoaster) and try training with gray scale images.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan I'm trying to convert the weights to 1 channel without retraining. at least the first or the first couple layers.

Comment: may be this can help ? https://gist.github.com/mohapatras/5d720cb19014ed573bcd3ed36c5929f5